# Unable to insert Text with Special Characters (/-&) from Excel to SQL using SSIS package

Tags: excel, ssis, upload

I am trying to insert a Company name column from Excel into a SQL Table using SSIS the Company Name Column contains Name as ABC\XYZ Company.com but while inserting the data I am getting below Errors

I am Using Flat file source and the file is in .csv format

Errors are below

SSIS package "C:\Users\C1363\source\repos\MAD Upload\MAD Upload\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The processing of file "D:\MAD\April_Mad_Report_2022.csv" has started.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC02020A1 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "MerchantName" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
Error: 0xC020902A at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[MerchantName]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[MerchantName]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
Error: 0xC0202092 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: An error occurred while processing file "D:\MAD\April_Mad_Report_2022.csv" on data row 169.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The processing of file "D:\MAD\April_Mad_Report_2022.csv" has ended.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\C1363\source\repos\MAD Upload\MAD Upload\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[19668] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: error on data row 169.  what is there?

Answer (score 0):

That is a data truncation error, please see below extract from your error message

> Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "MerchantName" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."

As a default SSIS flatfile connections sets the column length to 50, I'm guessing that some of your Merchant Names are longer than 50. Check your flat file connection properties under advanced and make sure that MerchantNames have the same length as the table you are inserting into. Please see below screenshot of a mock flat file connection

[image: Flat File Connection Manager]

Additionally you can redirect the truncation error to a record set destination, add a data viewer to the error output to see what the actual line looks like that is failing on the truncation error

[image: Error redirect]

Comment: I tired doing the same till there is an issue getting the same error i changed Merchant Names length to 1000 and check still getting the same Error

Comment: If the error states that a truncation error is happening on MerchantName even with 1000 chars then at least on of the records in your csv is longer than 1000. Can you try to send error lines to a Record Set Destination and then add a Data Viewer to the error output? Will update my answer with screenshots

Comment: Hi @Ockert thanks a lot for the help I got the solution for the same. What I did was just ignored the Error added a Derived Column. Took the Error Line and Ignored the Error for Merchant name. The Data Got inserted successfully.